# How to remove tabs/spacing while reading a XML file in python?

Tags: python, xml

Using `xml.etree.ElementTree` to read in a file, example.xml, how could the file be read such that indentation's are removed?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

Currently using,

```
root = ElementTree.parse('example.xml').getroot()
ElementTree.dump(root)
```

When the ElementTree.dump executes, I get what is above. What I would like to do, is read in the file and have an object with no indentations. This will be used to append another 'catalog' node to the original. The output below is what is desired.

```
<catalog><book id="bk101"><author>Gambardella, Matthew</author><title>XML Developer's Guide</title><genre>Computer</genre><price>44.95</price><publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date><description>An in-depth look at creating applicationswith XML.</description></book></catalog>
```

If the example is still kept in pretty form, and I use `root.append(newInformation)`, I receive the following

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <catalog>
       <book id="bk101">
          <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
          <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
          <genre>Computer</genre>
          <price>44.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
          <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
          with XML.</description>
       </book>
    </catalog><catalog><book id="bk101"><author>Gambardella, Matthew</author><title>XML Developer's Guide</title><genre>Computer</genre><price>44.95</price><publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date><description>An in-depth look at creating applicationswith XML.</description></book></catalog>
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way but I'm open to suggestions/ideas on how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

I suggest u could try to use lxml

```py
from lxml import etree
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = etree.parse("example.xml",parser=parser)
print(etree.tostring(tree))
```

output

```
b'<catalog><book id="bk101"><author>Gambardella, Matthew</author><title>XML Developer\'s Guide</title><genre>Computer</genre><price>44.95</price><publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date><description>An in-depth look at creating applications \n      with XML.</description></book></catalog>'
```

there will be a little different from your example.
It will keep "\n" from "An in-depth look at creating applications \n      with XML." ,because it's in the sentence from the begin.
If u want to remove,u could use "replace()"